# Combine itertools.product and range in one loop without creating cartesian product from the range

Tags: python

I want to be able to create a loop that does a cross product of two lists (first_list and second_list) and also in parallel loops through the range from 0 to (len(first_list) * len(second_list)) - 1.

The code below is wrong but it gives the idea of what I want to do.

```
for first_list_element, second_list_element, i in zip(
    itertools.product(
        first_list,
        second_list,
    ),
    range(len(first_list) * len(second_list)),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the `for-loop` of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for accessing to `range from 0 to (len(first_list) * len(second_list)) - 1`

```
from itertools import product

fl = [2,3]
fs = [4,5,6]

for idx, (l, s) in enumerate(product(*[fl,fs])):
    print(idx, (l,s))
```

---

```
0 (2, 4)
1 (2, 5)
2 (2, 6)
3 (3, 4)
4 (3, 5)
5 (3, 6)
```